# Sort array by value within secondary array php

Tags: php, arrays

Below I have an array that I generate, I need to order each by the 3rd [2] values.

Array:

```
{
aknox: {
    0: "28",
    1: "39",
    2: "71.79"
    },
    lphillips: {
    0: "81",
    1: "106",
    2: "76.42"
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    lphillips: {
    0: "81",
    1: "106",
    2: "76.42"
    },
    aknox: {
    0: "28",
    1: "39",
    2: "71.79"
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
usort($ccstats, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a[2], $b[2]);
});
```

`$ccstats` being the array.

This returns the array in ascending order when I tried to make array keys in descending order i.e. "akonx" and "lphillips" get lost and turned into 0 and 1

Any help appreciated

Comment: use `uasort` and the inverse of what you have `strcmp($b[2], $a[2]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve keys use [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort):

```
uasort($ccstats, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a[2], $b[2]);
});
```

If you say that you have `ascending` order but want `descending`, then just swap arguments in `strcmp`

```
uasort($ccstats, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($b[2], $a[2]);
});
```